# Stop rsync transfer where there's less than 5% of free space or inode count left?

Tags: rsync

Is there a way to force rsync to exit before it exhausts free space or inode count?

I have a server with, say, 100GB of small files, I want to transfer them to a different server that has 80GB of free space and a bunch of inodes. I don't care that some files won't transfer, but I don't want the smaller server to have less than x% of free space/inodes because of rsync.

Comment: One potential solution is to set up disk quota on the remote server.

Comment: Or a cronjob that kills all rsync processes when the disk runs out. Ugly, but effective.

Comment: rsync has no facility for this built-in. Use a wrapper script that first checks the destination.